# How to use Brain.js forecasting?

Tags: javascript, machine-learning, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to wrap my head around how it works, but I am having difficulties.

I have no idea if this is the proper way to do it, as I was unable to find clear tutorials.

**The data is a bunch of monthly sales ordered by descending date, and the goal is to predict the next sales value.**

```
const brain = require("brain.js");

let data = [996354, 2779977, 950792, 907340, 1284286, 1266783, 822415, 686550, 1758690, 1186851, 1441859, 1464443, 912951, 1421954, 1521516, 918052, 770238, 1417087, 919990, 1334906, 1224836, 939102, 1063518, 1224231, 877331, 1021506, 874522, 940530, 683876, 1121152, 737414, 1166480, 1082231, 822357, 1146419, 1430051, 631730, 1215160, 868301, 803220, 1182219, 935233, 594446, 1268709, 1160274, 984417, 1124874, 1358540, 878604, 1062942, 1032730, 695323, 1092530, 702907, 986607, 897194, 957222, 935261, 896631, 1028320, 710657, 771455, 795649, 870530, 1251944, 676158, 595391, 861075, 1260068, 1011426, 1059614, 1265080, 1567216, 490529];

const net = new brain.recurrent.LSTMTimeStep({
    inputSize: 1,
    hiddenLayers: [10],
    outputSize: 1
});

net.train([data], {
    learningRate: 0.005,
    errorTresh: 0.02,
    // log: (stats) => console.log(stats)
})

console.log(net.forecast(data, 1))
// [ -0.020625554025173187 ]
// [ -0.008880683220922947 ]
// [ 0.11804535984992981 ]
```

Each time I run this, I get different results, which I can't decipher.

Comment: Seems the only "tutorial" is here https://github.com/BrainJS/brain.js/blob/master/examples/javascript/predict-numbers.js In case you don't know there is also js version of tensorflow

Comment: You're using errorTresh instead of errorThresh

Answer (score -1):

You need to normalize the inputs to be between 0 and 1.  Then after running the net, you can denormalize the outputs to their original scale.

Comment: I did that. Why does the forecast give different results each time it runs?

Comment: Can you share more of your code? Perhaps then we could answer more specifically.

Comment: anyone find a solution to this or have a good example using forecast with large numbers that works?